# Where can I get a list of reflection modifier values?

Tags: php, reflection, introspection

[This function](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmodifiers.php) returned `524320` for one my classes. If I run it through [getModifierNames](http://php.net/manual/en/reflection.getmodifiernames.php), it tells me:

```
>> Reflection::getModifierNames(524320)
array (
  0 => 'abstract',
)
```

Which is correct, but 524320 isn't a power of 2, so it must have some other flags? Actually, if we look at it's binary representation, `10100111` it looks like it has 5 flags set. So what are the other 4, and where can I find a list of all of them?

**Edit:** Now I'm confused... the representation is actually `10000000000000100000`, according to [this](http://acc6.its.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~gurwitz/core5/nav2tool.html). Which makes sense, because that corresponds to "explicit abstract class". Oh... I bet this was an overflow issue now that I'm thinking about...must investigate a bit more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the ZEND_ACC_* constants in http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_compile.h#144

Mind that some of these are internal and are not exported in anyway to userspace. The ones exported to userspace ones can be found in http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php and other classes.